# Select an element with random ID via JQuery

Tags: php, jquery, css

I have an element that it's ID will generate randomly:

```
<?php echo "<input id='input'".uniqid()." />"?>
```

How can access it via JQuery? I want access it like this: `("#input*")`. Do can use `*` token in JQuery?

Comment: The `*` will pick any element.

Comment: What is generated output?

Comment: while making your `id` you could store all them in a JS global array

Comment: Why are you giving elements that aren't unique unique id's? wouldn't a class make more sense here?

Comment: @Jai: like this: `input-button516c397a61866`

Comment: @msoa i think niels and praveen answered that.

Comment: Adding a class to all randomly selectable elements and then choosing a random element among those returned by getElementsByClassName seems clearer imo.

Comment: **@KevinB:** I need it in Yii framework, for a complex page that have several forms.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You can do:

```
$("[id^='input']")
```

See the documentation of starts with: http://api.jquery.com/attribute-starts-with-selector/

Answer (score 2):

Use a [regex selector](http://api.jquery.com/attribute-starts-with-selector/) this way:

```
$("[id^='input']")
```

Answer (score 1):

If you want to access the id like `$("#input*")` then you can have a look at [`Attribute Contains Selector [name*="value"]`](http://api.jquery.com/attribute-contains-selector/):

```
$('input[id*="input"]')
```